# Add code to HTML header with javascript in Cloudflare Workers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm using Cloudflare workers to proxy a domain name and need to add some code into the header of the HTML page directly before the closing `</head>` tag.

I've tried using `.replace` in a few places but it never seems to add this.

Here's my current code:

```
const config = {
  basic: {
    upstream: 'https://example.com/',
    mobileRedirect: 'https://example.com/',
  },

  optimization: {
    apps: true,
    cacheEverything: true,
    cacheTtl: 0,
    mirage: true,
    polish: 'off',
    minify: {
      javascript: true,
      css: true,
      html: true,
    },
  },
};

async function fetchAndApply(request) {
  const region = request.headers.get('cf-ipcountry') || '';
  const ipAddress = request.headers.get('cf-connecting-ip') || '';
  const userAgent = request.headers.get('user-agent') || '';

  const requestURL = new URL(request.url);
  let upstreamURL = null;

  upstreamURL = new URL(config.basic.upstream);

  requestURL.protocol = upstreamURL.protocol;
  requestURL.host = upstreamURL.host;
  requestURL.pathname = upstreamURL.pathname + requestURL.pathname;

  let newRequest;
  if (request.method === 'GET' || request.method === 'HEAD') {
    newRequest = new Request(requestURL, {
      cf: {
        apps: config.optimization.apps,
        cacheEverything: config.optimization.cacheEverything,
        cacheTtl: config.optimization.cacheTtl,
        mirage: config.optimization.mirage,
        polish: config.optimization.polish,
        minify: config.optimization.minify,
      },
      method: request.method,
      headers: request.headers,
    });
  } else {
    const requestBody = await request.text();
    newRequest = new Request(requestURL, {
      cf: {
        apps: config.optimization.apps,
        cacheEverything: config.optimization.cacheEverything,
        cacheTtl: config.optimization.cacheTtl,
        mirage: config.optimization.mirage,
        polish: config.optimization.polish,
        minify: config.optimization.minify,
      },
      method: request.method,
      headers: request.headers,
      body: requestBody,
    });
  }

  const fetchedResponse = await fetch(newRequest);

  const modifiedResponseHeaders = new Headers(fetchedResponse.headers);
  if (modifiedResponseHeaders.has('x-pjax-url')) {
    const pjaxURL = new URL(modifiedResponseHeaders.get('x-pjax-url'));
    pjaxURL.protocol = requestURL.protocol;
    pjaxURL.host = requestURL.host;
    pjaxURL.pathname = pjaxURL.path.replace(requestURL.pathname, '/');

    modifiedResponseHeaders.set(
      'x-pjax-url',
      pjaxURL.href,
    );
  }

  return new Response(
    fetchedResponse.body,
    {
      headers: modifiedResponseHeaders,
      status: fetchedResponse.status,
      statusText: fetchedResponse.statusText,
    },
  );
}

addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(fetchAndApply(event.request));
});
```

Any ideas on what the easiest way to do this would be?

Comment: This code is too large and complicated for us to read through. Can you narrow it down to something demonstrating your problem? It sounds like you should be registering an element handler on `head`, and then using `element.append()` to add content to the end of it?

Comment: @KentonVarda updated and removed about a third of the code.  I tried `append` and `replace` in a few areas, but couldn't get it to work.  Sorry, was planning for this project to be much easier because I didn't think this would need to be done at all.  I was under the impression that settings `apps` to `true` would allows apps to run and I could just easily do this with the `Add HTML` app in CloudFlare.

Comment: I'm confused, your question is about how to modify the response body but your code doesn't even attempt to do this, so I can't tell what you're having trouble with. You should be using `HTMLRewriter` to rewrite the HTML body...